# Reusable Registration component

Tags: jakarta-ee, registration, reusability

Is there a reusable registration component (or Sign Up Component) based on Java EE that I can use in my application?

By registration component I mean a set of basic details (should be customizable) that the user need to enter to Register in a website. It might be a set of JSP/HTML pages which needs to populate the information in some DataBase. There might be some SQL scripts available for creating the required tables/columns

Could you please let me know?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have the following options, depending on your needs and your future website user base:

1. Implement your own pages but with some help from the popular libraries like [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org) or [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) module
2. Use some fully-featured authentication mechanism like [OpenAM](http://www.forgerock.com/openam.html)
3. Forget about managing auth yourself and use available options served by Google/Twitter/Facebook etc. Great library for working with the 3rd option is [SocialAuth](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/) which I have tried myself and I can recommend.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I'm looking for a reusable registration component. For example, we have reusable templates for the forums. Something similar to that.